Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDexDebug'. > Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDexDebug'.


Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
Failed to transform classes.jar (project :firebase_auth) to match attributes {artifactType=android-dex, asm-transformed-variant=NONE, com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr=7.3.0, com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr=debug, com.android.build.gradle.internal.attributes.VariantAttr=debug, dexing-enable-desugaring=true, dexing-enable-jacoco-instrumentation=false, dexing-is-debuggable=true, dexing-min-sdk=19, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> Execution failed for DexingWithClasspathTransform: F:\reddit_2\build\firebase_auth\intermediates\runtime_library_classes_jar\debug\classes.jar.
> Error while dexing.
Failed to transform classes.jar (project :firebase_storage) to match attributes {artifactType=android-dex, asm-transformed-variant=NONE, com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr=7.3.0, com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr=debug, com.android.build.gradle.internal.attributes.VariantAttr=debug, dexing-enable-desugaring=true, dexing-enable-jacoco-instrumentation=false, dexing-is-debuggable=true, dexing-min-sdk=19, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> Execution failed for DexingWithClasspathTransform: F:\reddit_2\build\firebase_storage\intermediates\runtime_library_classes_jar\debug\classes.jar.
> Error while dexing.
Failed to transform classes.jar (project :cloud_firestore) to match attributes {artifactType=android-dex, asm-transformed-variant=NONE, com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr=7.3.0, com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr=debug, com.android.build.gradle.internal.attributes.VariantAttr=debug, dexing-enable-desugaring=true, dexing-enable-jacoco-instrumentation=false, dexing-is-debuggable=true, dexing-min-sdk=19, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> Execution failed for DexingWithClasspathTransform: F:\reddit_2\build\cloud_firestore\intermediates\runtime_library_classes_jar\debug\classes.jar.
> Error while dexing.
Failed to transform classes.jar (project :firebase_core) to match attributes {artifactType=android-dex, asm-transformed-variant=NONE, com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr=7.3.0, com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr=debug, com.android.build.gradle.internal.attributes.VariantAttr=debug, dexing-enable-desugaring=true, dexing-enable-jacoco-instrumentation=false, dexing-is-debuggable=true, dexing-min-sdk=19, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> Execution failed for DexingWithClasspathTransform: F:\reddit_2\build\firebase_core\intermediates\runtime_library_classes_jar\debug\classes.jar.
> Error while dexing.
Failed to transform classes.jar (project :google_sign_in_android) to match attributes {artifactType=android-dex, asm-transformed-variant=NONE, com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr=7.3.0, com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr=debug, com.android.build.gradle.internal.attributes.VariantAttr=debug, dexing-enable-desugaring=true, dexing-enable-jacoco-instrumentation=false, dexing-is-debuggable=true, dexing-min-sdk=19, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> Execution failed for DexingWithClasspathTransform: F:\reddit_2\build\google_sign_in_android\intermediates\runtime_library_classes_jar\debug\classes.jar.
> Error while dexing.


Try:


Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.
Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

BUILD FAILED in 1m 25s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
This is the error I'm getting whenever I try adding dependecies(Firebase or of the sort) in .yaml file. Tried changing versions of kotlin, java, gradle. Nothing works.

I think I found the solution myself after posting the question an hour ago.
It was that I was using an older version of dart sdk the whole time. Just write the following commands in the terminal to upgrade and it works fine.

flutter channel beta
flutter upgrade

